# Clearing local storage on running electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am writing an electron application that uses local storage as a persistence mechanism for the redux store. However, when I build the production version the dev version of local storage remains.

How do you automatically clear local storage when packing your app using electron-builder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the Local Storage folder from within the building script, on Windows this would be `%AppData%\Electron\Local Storage`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a pre-build script, like this one (I only build for windows, tho)

```
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra')
const localPath = 'C:/Users/' + require("os").userInfo().username + '/AppData/Roaming/YOURAPPNAME/Local Storage'
fsExtra.emptyDirSync(localPath)
```

saved this into a js file that I run before building.